# How do I invert colours on ngx-charts-heat-map

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, ngx-charts

I'm using `ngx-charts-heat-map` to create a heat map. This is all going well enough, the map works, however, one small detail I can't figure out.
At the moment the higher the value of a cell, the more red it gets, and the lower the value, the less red it gets.
In my context however, a large number is good, a small number is bad, so I'd like the colours to be inverted, and I'm not sure how to do that here. Essentially, I want the user to be drawn to the things with low values, not high values.
Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, color scheme.

`scheme` is an object containing the color scheme of the chart. You can use it with predefined colors like so:

```
<ngx-charts-heat-map
  [view]="view"
  scheme="neons"
  ...
```

Predefined list of named colormaps can be checked out [here](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/heat-map).

Or define your custom object like so:

(in template)

```
<ngx-charts-heat-map
  [view]="view"
  [scheme]="colorScheme"
  ...
```

(in component)

```
colorScheme = {
  domain: ['#5AA454', '#E44D25', '#CFC0BB', '#7aa3e5', '#a8385d', '#aae3f5']
};
```

Taken straight from the [official demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-heat-map-chart?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts).

Adopt the color scheme to your needs.

Comment: thanks, I completely missed the fact that the `domain` defines the different colours the map will go through.
From left (0) to right (100).

Comment: fyi, for a red to green flow I now chose this: <br>

```
  colourScheme = {
    domain: ["#C91414", "#E3071D", "#FF7E01", "#FFBE00", "#75AD6F", "#1D7044"],
  };
```

Comment: You could also try `color="flame"`, it should be pretty similar to what you need (for some reason, it's red-yellow-green). And yea, my logic basically was that if you have an option to define a custom color map, inverting it would be trivial.